# Listen for Spring Integration TCP Connection events

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-integration

My objective is to listen for particular tcp connection events and perform some tasks with it.

By implementing `ApplicationEventPublisher`, I can see the events firing.

```
@Component
public class TestEventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisher {

   @Override
   public void publishEvent(Object event) {
       LOG.info("Event Fired - {}", event.getClass());
   }
}
```

> INFO  [globalTaskExecutor-2] logger - Event Fired - class org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionOpenEvent
>
> INFO  [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-3] logger - Event Fired - class org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionCloseEvent

So I added the listeners for it, but they do not get executed.

```
@Component
public class TestListeners {

   @EventListener(TcpConnectionOpenEvent.class)
   public void doSomethingWhenConnectionIsOpen() {
        LOG.info("----------------**************** CONNECTION OPEN EVENT FIRED ****************** -----------------------"); // No log shows up
    }

    @EventListener(TcpConnectionFailedEvent.class)
    public void doSomethingElseWhenConnectionFails() {
        LOG.info("----------------**************** CONNECTION ATTEMPT FAILED EVENT FIRED ****************** -----------------------"); // No Log shows up
    }

}
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your publisher doesn't actually publish anything, it just logs the event.

In order to use `@EventListener`, you must use the built in `ApplicationEventPublisher` provided by Spring (which is actually the application context).

The TCP components implement `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` so Spring will automatically inject the built-in publisher (as long as the component is managed by Spring). If you want to intercept the publishing, your publisher must implement `ApplicationEventPublisherAware`, log the event, then call the real publisher provided by Spring.

You should also add the event parameter to the listeners.